# Fill in text in HTML5

Tags: css, html, project

I have a simple question: I am currently creating my portfolio in html

[image]

I wish that by clicking on the image, I can write the description of my choice. For the moment it shows me this:

[image]

I give you the party of the corresponding code below.

Thank you again for your help !

```
<!-- item -->
                <div class="project-item">
                    <!-- ==> Put your thumbnail as a background -->
                    <a href="img/portfolio/p2.jpg" class="project-thumbnail nivobox" data-lightbox-gallery="portfolio" style="background-image: url('img/portfolio/thumb-p2.jpg');">
                        <!-- project-description -->
                        <div class="project-description-wrapper">
                            <div class="project-description">
                                <!-- project name -->
                                <h2 class="project-title">Project Title</h2>
                                <!-- /project name -->
                                <span class="see-more">Project Tags</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /project-description -->
                    </a>
                </div>          
                <!-- /item -->
```

Comment: Add all relevant code please. Images are hardly debugged.

Comment: What are you looking for, what have you tried, what have you researched, you want a text field to appear when the image is clicked so you can add your description for that image...yes/no

Comment: I do not think all the code is necessary.
I sent you the code corresponding to my problem. thks

Comment: @Jason Delaney YES I WANT THIS PLEASE

Comment: Id suggest you look into some html input tags and add them to your frame, to store the data that would be up to you, localstorage could be an option

Comment: here is a super website you can research lots of technologies, SO is here to help you not here to do things for you, I suggested to you things that might be of use to you please don't reply with I don't know how to, help yourself. what would the point in me showing you the solution you still wouldn't understand it, HAPPY LEARNING https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what framework (if at all) you're using, but my go-to solution for creating websites, is MaterializeCSS. 
And oh look, they got something that exactly matches what you want (as far as I can understand, let me know if it doesn't).

Here it is:

```
<!-- MATERIAL BOXED-->
        <h1>MATERIAL BOXED</h1>

        <img src="http://materializecss.com/images/sample-1.jpg" alt="" class="materialboxed" data-caption="Here is an image caption">
```

The only change that you must do in your code, is to import the Materialize library and jQuery necessary, all of which are in their [official page](http://materializecss.com/).

Hope this can help you solve your problem, it might look a bit un-orthodox but it gets the job done, at looks pretty nice doing so ;)

Comment: Thank you for your answer fiend.
I want to avoid importing a library into my script. I'm sure there's a simple way to add a description when I click on the image.

Comment: Actually, using a framework might be the easiest and most simple way to do what you want, since doing it in just plain CSS/HTML might be possible, but oh boy is that going to take a long time.